# Find the interval of convergence $\sum_{n=o}^{\infty} x^{n(n+1)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find the interval of convergence $\sum_{n=o}^{\infty} x^{n(n+1)}$?

$\underline{Attempt}$

By Root Test,
$$ \alpha=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\bigg|x^{n(n+1)}\bigg|^{\frac{1}{n}}=x\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\bigg|x^n\bigg|$$

For Convergence $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\bigg|x^n\bigg| $$ should be convergence ,so interval of convergence should be $|x|\leq1$

Is my attempt correct? Please mention if there is any method other than that?

Comment: The ratio test also works.

Comment: Remember that $\alpha=1$ is an inconclusive case for the Root Test. So your method correctly deduces convergence for $|x|<1$ and divergence for $|x|>1$, but you need some other method to decide the cases $\pm1$ (not that they're difficult). Minor detail: $\alpha$ should equal $|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\cdots$ rather than $x\lim_{n\to\infty}\cdots$.

Comment: @GregMartin Got it thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exponent is always even, the convergence will be absolute.

The series obviously diverges for $|x|\ge1$. And as it is a "subset" of the geometric series, it converges for $|x|<1.$

Comment: Got it. It was a typo. If you can please use ratio text?

Comment: @DARK: that's your job.

Comment: I tried it  but I don't know how to apply it. Is it$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n(n+1)}}{x^{(n+2)(n+3)}}  ?$

Comment: @DARK: why $n+2$ ?

Comment: Oh It should be $n+1$ and $n+2$